# Does a company registered at AMEX has to follow the $1 minimum price rule if traded on NYSE?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

NYSE's Rule Section 802.01C stipulates that the price of a stock must not fall below $1 for a consecutive 30-day trading period, nor should it have an average stock price closing below $2 in the same period. If this happens, the stock is considered non-compliant, and the company has six months to bring its share price and the average share price back above $1. If the company fails to do so or fails to acknowledge the fact, suspension and delisting procedures can take place.

For example, `IMUC` is registered at `AMEX`, but traded on `NYSE`. It has been under $1 for over 30 days, but no non-compliance note has been issued. Is that because it is not registered on NYSE?

Does a company registered at AMEX has to follow the $1 minimum price rule if traded on NYSE?

Also, does the rule applies to 30 business (trade) days, or calendar days?

Comment: What does this have to do with your personal finances?

Comment: Because I personally invest my personal money in the stock market. I thought it was clear.

Comment: This rule has nothing to do with you.  Typically when a company has to contend with these kinds of exchange rules it simply reverse splits its shares to get up to the minimum share price.  The timelines and rule application have nothing to do with you unless you are an executive at the company.

Answer (score 1):

> Is that because it is not registered on NYSE?

Probably.  The exchange can trade a security in two ways: One, if they choose to manage the listing (i.e. the stock is listed on NYSE); and two, if they decide to trade it because it is listed on another national securities exchange, in which case the exchange rules of the *exchange that listed the company* would apply.

> Does a company registered at AMEX has to follow the $1 minimum price rule if traded on NYSE?

It depends on NYSE's rules.  If NYSE's rules offer an exemption from their own listing criteria if the security is listed on another securities exchange, then the NYSE listing may not be subject to rule 802.01C.  Looking at the rulebook containing the rule, it appears to be primarily relevant to companies that are listed on NYSE and not securities that are hosted on other exchanges.

The AMEX (primary) listing would have its own rules, which might be the same but not necessarily.

> Also, does the rule applies to 30 business (trade) days, or calendar days?

A `a consecutive 30 trading-day period` would appear to be trading days.

To fully answer the question, you should review both the Amex and NYSE exchange rules relating to listings, particularly where they are talking about securities listed on multiple exchanges.

Note: AMEX is now called NYSE MKT Equities